# Describing blow-ups locally

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Let $X$ be a scheme and $U$ an open subscheme of $X$. Let $C \subseteq X$ be a closed subscheme of $X$ that is properly contained in $U$. I would like to know if we have $$\text{Bl}_{C}(X) \cong \text{Bl}_{C}(U) \cup (X \setminus U)$$ or even equality? The notation $\text{Bl}_A(B)$ means the blow-up of a scheme $A$ along its closed subscheme $B \subseteq A$. We may assume all of our schemes are affine + of finite type over some field $K$ if that is needed. Any answer/reference is appreciated.

Comment: One thing that I noticed right away: $C$ might not be closed in $X$. As a simple example, we could have $C=U$ but $U$ not a connected component of $X$. (there are plenty of other examples).

Comment: @Dave Is the statement true if $C$ is indeed closed in $X$?

Comment: Where is the union taking place?

Comment: @hunter where the blow-up lives in. I'm trying to use the fact that anywhere that I am not blowing up at stays the same.